# No puedo usar MessageEmbed en discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Mi código:

```
const { Client, Intents, **MessageEmbed** } = require('discord.js');

const discord = require('discord.js');

require("dotenv").config();

var users = [];

**const comandsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()**.setColor([0, 255, 255]);

const client = new discord.Client({
    intents: [0, 0, 0],
  });
```

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')at new MessageEmbed**

Comment: no hace falta que hagas `discord.Client` pues ya estas obteniendo `Client` en la primera linea, por lo que ese `discord = require('discord.js')` está de más.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo elimine, pero de todas maneras sigue sin funcionar por culpa del mismo error

Comment: Ese es todo el código que tienes? Según yo parece estar todo bien. También, actualiza el código de la pregunta

Comment: Realmente el codigo que sigue no son mas que sentencias if y el error me marca la linea de codigo 10, que es esta: const comandsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()

Comment: Podrías agregar el error completo que te aparece en la consola? además indica que versión de discord.js estas usando

Comment: Ese es el problema, tengo la version 11.6.4, estoy intentado actualizarlo a la 14, y no tengo idea de como hacerlo ajsja

Comment: Entonces puedes mirar esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62173144/15026532) en el sitio en ingles

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora esa misma linea me da este error: ValidationError: Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead, pero bueno porlomenos avance un poco

Comment: Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/552173/edit) tu pregunta agregando todos los detalles de tu avance y el nuevo problema que tienes

Comment: Quizá tengas que crear el Embed luego de haber creado el Client